# "There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 52,Token in error = Data]"

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to select a set of data for a ComboBox based on the selection of the previous ComboBox. I have been lead to believe it is the SELECT statement in the second method, but I cannot figure out why it isn't working. When I run the application I receive this error: "There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 52,Token in error = Data]" I have attempted using Parameter.AddWithValue, cmd.Parameters.Add, and also setting the value as a string to no avail. Would anyone mind teaching me how to correctly resolve this? Thank you.

The setup of the database is as follows:

Cities

- CityId (PK, int, not null)
- Name (nchar(20), null)
- rowguid (uniqueidentifier, not null)

Parks

- ParkId (PK, int, not null)
- CityId (FK, int, not null)
- Name (nchar(30), null)
- rowguid (uniqueidentifier)

Here is the method:

```
private void cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboCities.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = \Program Files\ParkSurvey\ParkSurvey.sdf; Persist Security Info = False; Password = *");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM [Parks] WHERE CityId =" + cboCities.SelectedValue + "ORDER BY Name ASC";
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        cboParks.ValueMember = "ParkId";
        cboParks.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboParks.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cboParks.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned that you tried parametrizing the query but if the error you are getting now is being thrown with the code you posted, then I would think it has to do with the fact that you are missing a blank space before "ORDER BY"; otherwise, the query executed will be something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM [Parks] WHERE CityId =5ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Which is clearly invalid SQL.

Your query should be:

```
"SELECT Name FROM [Parks] WHERE CityId =" + cboCities.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

With that being said, I'd look at parametrizing the query to avoid SQL Injection attacks. Using `cmd.Paramters.AddWithValue` is a better approach than writing this inline SQL statement.

Your query could be written then as:

```
"SELECT Name FROM [Parks] WHERE CityId = @CityID ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

And you can add the parameter as so:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID",cboCities.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Actually, my original method I had correctly adjusted that space. Following your recommendation, I am now receiving this error: "No mapping exists from DbType System.Data.DataRowView to a known SqlCeType."

Comment: @ZakaryDrinan if it's complaining about `DataRowView` it seems to me that cboCities.SelectedValue is somehow returning a `DataRowView` instead of an int. How are you binding the data to `cboCities`?

Comment: cboCities.SelectedValue is the ValueMember of the initial method, and the initial method is identical to the second method bar for the SELECT statement, if that's what you mean.